# How to respond to local notification when app is closed in iOS10?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, ios10

How to respond to local notification when app is completly closed (not in background)?

When the app is running in the background or foreground everything works fine. But when the app is closed and I'm trying to answer to a notification, only `"application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions"` gets called, `"userNotificationCenter didRecive response`" isn't answering.

I found this question ([How to handle UNNotificationAction when app is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655180/how-to-handle-unnotificationaction-when-app-is-closed)) but in my case it doesn't work neither at a real device nor in a simulator.

I also noticed that the function `"UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications()"` returns `nil` when I'm responding to a notification while app is closed.

Comment: what code do you have now and how are you setting up your notifications?

Comment: Are you setting the `UNNotificationCenter` delegate in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` or `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions`?

Comment: if I understand right u must check launchOptions dictionary in "applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions" method for key @"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey" and if success handle u notification

Comment: I noticed right now that I moved delegate from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to separate function which is called in `didReceive response` function. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For **iOS 9 and lower** in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` you would check if `launchOptions` contains `localNotification: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey`. If so you would know that the app just freshly started because of local notification (i.e. user clicked on notification).

For **iOS 10+** you **must** register your `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` in `application(_:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` or `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`.

Your delegate's function:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
```

will be called if your app freshly started or it was just sitting in the background. 
The advantage of this new API is that there is only one place to handle local notification actions.

Comment: How we register this in function? Could you put a code here?

Comment: This isn't responding to the notification though - you would need the app to run without interaction like it used to.